# Is monthly subscription Haram For Tournament

Tags: halal-haram, game

If I arrange many halal games tournament by taking only monthly subscription then will it be a haram project.

In that case, user will pay only a monthly subscription fees like $1 for whole month. then he will join all the tournaments for that month. If he wins a tournament then he will be rewarded with some cash according to that particular tournament reward money. If he loose then he will not get any prize and he will not loose anything else.

We will take only monthly subscription fees and except that user will not provide any fees. So is it a haram project?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Does the subscriber receive any other benefits for their monthly fee, or does it only allow access to these tournaments?

Comment: Only allow to this tournaments

Answer (score 1):

Like brother Ibrahim Imran Atheism Refuted stated, the type of content that you have within your tournament definitely counts. If the tournament has anything that is haraam within it, then the prize money will be counted as haraam.

[This](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/114530/football-soccer-competitions) fatwa states that if the competitions are not being funded by the people competing within them, then it is halaal.

You are charging a monthly fee to the players of these tournaments. If the tournament prize money comes from the monthly fee, then it is haraam. If the monthly fee is just for the right to enter the tournaments where a prize will be given then [this](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/89746/ruling-on-educational-contests-in-newspapers) fatwa states that it is still haraam. Read point 1 on that page as it states that paying a fee just so that there's a *possibility* of winning a prize is not permissible.

If there was no monthly fee then there would be zero loss on the player's side, but since there is a monthly fee there is something to be lost.

Think of it like playing the lottery. I pay up front for the right to enter the lottery (monthly fee). I choose numbers not knowing if they'll come out (enter tournament not knowing if I will win). If I win the lottery I make money (If I win the tournament I win money).

Answer (score 0):

Assalamaulaikum Brother,

I think this is okay as you are ensuring the participant that he will not lose any money. But, you must ensure that. If he loses money, then it could fall into gambling as he has no idea if he will win or lose and what the effects may be.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/14220/internet-competitions

Comment: Thank you sir, for your reply. I am taking a monthly subscription fees. Everyone have to pay that fees... winner will get reward but loosers will not loose anything else except that monthly fees.. I am concern about this